# Haskell instances under type variable conditions

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Starting with a concrete instance of my question, we all know (and love) the `Monad` type class:

```
class ... => Monad m where
  return :: a -> m a
  (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> mb
  ...
```

Consider the following would-be instance, where we modify the standard list/"nondeterminism" instance using [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) to retain only one copy of each "outcome":

```
type DistinctList a = DL { dL :: [a] }
instance Monad DistinctList where
  return = DL . return
  x >>= f = DL . nub $ (dL x) >>= (dL . f)
```

...Do you spot the error?  The problem is that `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` and so `x >>= f` is only defined under the condition `f :: Eq b => a -> DistinctList b`, whereas the compiler demands `f :: a -> DistinctList b`.  Is there some way I can proceed anyway?

Stepping back, suppose I have a would-be instance that is only defined under some condition on the parametric type's *variable*.  I understand that this is generally not allowed because other code written with the type class cannot be guaranteed to supply parameter values that obey the condition.  But are there circumstances where this still can be carried out?  If so, how?

Comment: That's a classic problem, and the reason why e.g. `Data.Set` is not a monad. You might want to look at this [set-monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad)

Comment: How would you define the `Functor` instance without breaking the `fmap id = id` law?

Comment: @4castle the identity law is actually no problem at all, provided you don't _start out_ with a `DistinctList` that has duplicates in it (which would presumably be prevented by only exporting smart constructors). More problematic is the composition law, but this too can be fulfilled given sensible assumptions of how an `Eq` instance should behave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of the technique applied in [set-monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/set-monad) to your case.

Note there is, as there must be, some "cheating". The structure includes extra value constructors to represent "return" and "bind". These act as suspended computations that need to be run. The `Eq` instance is there part of the `run` function, while the constructors that create the "suspension" are `Eq` free.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import qualified Data.List            as L
import qualified Data.Functor         as F
import qualified Control.Applicative  as A
import Control.Monad

-- for reference, the bind operation to be implemented
-- bind operation requires Eq
dlbind :: Eq b => [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b] 
dlbind xs f = L.nub $ xs >>= f

-- data structure comes with incorporated return and bind 
-- `Prim xs` wraps a list into a DL   
data DL a where
  Prim   :: [a] -> DL a
  Return :: a -> DL a
  Bind   :: DL a -> (a -> DL b) -> DL b

-- converts a DL to a list 
run :: Eq a => DL a -> [a]
run (Prim xs)             = xs
run (Return x)            = [x]
run (Bind (Prim xs) f)    = L.nub $ concatMap (run . f) xs
run (Bind (Return x) f)   = run (f x)
run (Bind (Bind ma f) g)  = run (Bind ma (\a -> Bind (f a) g))

-- lifting of Eq and Show instance
-- Note: you probably should provide a different instance
--       one where eq doesn't depend on the position of the elements
--       otherwise you break functor laws (and everything else)
instance (Eq a) => Eq (DL a) where
  dxs == dys = run dxs == run dys

-- this "cheats", i.e. it will convert to lists in order to show. 
-- executing returns and binds in the process        
instance (Show a, Eq a) => Show (DL a) where
  show = show . run

-- uses the monad instance
instance F.Functor DL where
  fmap  = liftM 

-- uses the monad instance
instance A.Applicative DL where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap

-- builds the DL using Return and Bind constructors
instance Monad DL where
  return = Return
  (>>=)  = Bind

-- examples with bind for a "normal list" and a "distinct list"
list  =  [1,2,3,4] >>= (\x ->  [x `mod` 2, x `mod` 3])   
dlist = (Prim [1,2,3,4]) >>= (\x -> Prim [x `mod` 2, x `mod` 3])
```

---

And here is a dirty hack to make it more efficient, addressing the points raised below about evaluation of bind.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import qualified Data.List            as L
import qualified Data.Set             as S
import qualified Data.Functor         as F
import qualified Control.Applicative  as A
import Control.Monad


dlbind xs f = L.nub $ xs >>= f

data DL a where
  Prim   :: Eq a => [a] -> DL a
  Return :: a -> DL a
  Bind   :: DL b -> (b -> DL a) -> DL a
--  Fail   :: DL a  -- could be add to clear failure chains

run :: Eq a => DL a -> [a]
run (Prim xs)      = xs
run (Return x)     = [x]
run b@(Bind _ _)   =
  case foldChain b of 
    (Bind (Prim xs) f)   -> L.nub $ concatMap (run . f) xs
    (Bind (Return a) f)  -> run (f a)
    (Bind (Bind ma f) g) -> run (Bind ma (\a -> Bind (f a) g))

-- fold a chain ((( ... >>= f) >>= g) >>= h
foldChain :: DL u -> DL u  
foldChain (Bind b2 g) = stepChain $ Bind (foldChain b2) g 
foldChain dxs         = dxs

-- simplify (Prim _ >>= f) >>= g 
--   if  (f x = Prim _)
--   then reduce to (Prim _ >>= g)
--   else preserve  (Prim _ >>= f) >>= g 
stepChain :: DL u -> DL u
stepChain b@(Bind (Bind (Prim xs) f) g) =
  let dys = map f xs
      pms = [Prim ys   | Prim   ys <- dys]
      ret = [Return ys | Return ys <- dys]
      bnd = [Bind ys f | Bind ys f <- dys]
  in case (pms, ret, bnd) of
       -- ([],[],[]) -> Fail -- could clear failure
       (dxs@(Prim ys:_),[],[]) -> let Prim xs = joinPrims dxs (Prim $ mkEmpty ys)
                                  in Bind (Prim $ L.nub xs) g       
       _  -> b
stepChain dxs = dxs

-- empty list with type via proxy  
mkEmpty :: proxy a -> [a]
mkEmpty proxy = []

-- concatenate Prims in on Prim
joinPrims [] dys = dys 
joinPrims (Prim zs : dzs) dys = let Prim xs = joinPrims dzs dys in Prim (zs ++ xs)  

instance (Ord a) => Eq (DL a) where
  dxs == dys = run dxs == run dys

instance (Ord a) => Ord (DL a) where
  compare dxs dys = compare (run dxs) (run dys)

instance (Show a, Eq a) => Show (DL a) where
  show = show . run    

instance F.Functor DL where
  fmap  = liftM 

instance A.Applicative DL where
  pure  = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad DL where
  return = Return
  (>>=)  = Bind


-- cheating here, Prim is needed for efficiency 
return' x = Prim [x]

s =  [1,2,3,4] >>= (\x ->  [x `mod` 2, x `mod` 3])   
t = (Prim [1,2,3,4]) >>= (\x -> Prim [x `mod` 2, x `mod` 3]) 
r' = ((Prim [1..1000]) >>= (\x -> return' 1)) >>= (\x -> Prim [1..1000])
```

Comment: It cheats in another way: reassociating binds loses opportunities to eliminate duplicates in intermediate "sets". Compare the runtime of `dlbind (dlbind [1..1000] (const (return 1))) (\x -> [1..1000])` (instant) to `run ((>>=) ((>>=) (Prim [1..1000]) (const (return 1))) (\x -> Prim [1..1000]))` (takes a long time).

Comment: IOW, `DL` it just a ceremony around a plain list monad, and `run = nub`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes :/ The big culprit is `return` though, since you cannot impose equality on it. But you can impose on `Prim` and you can its equality constraint as a witness for bottom up simplifications. See my edit for a quick dirty hack to illustrate my point. Not saying it's great, but it's something.

Comment: @luqui yes I have to agree, but we probably can do a bit more with it. See the hack I posted addressing Daniel's example  (just put that together in a few of mins, more a proof of concept than anything else)

Comment: Very minor point: this only requires `{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}`, since it does not really involve GADTs.

Comment: @chi there's an existential in `Bind` though. Also in the second example with the efficiency hack, `Prim` requires an `Eq` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

If your type could be a Monad, then it would need to work in functions that are parameterized across all monads, or across all applicatives. But it can't, because people store all kinds of weird things in their monads. Most notably, functions are very often stored as the value in an applicative context. For example, consider:

```
pairs :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
pairs xs ys = (,) <$> xs <*> ys
```

Even though `a` and `b` are both `Eq`, in order to combine them into an `(a, b)` pair, we needed to first fmap a function into `xs`, briefly producing a value of type `f (b -> (a, b))`. If we let `f` be your DL monad, we see that this can't work, because this function type has no `Eq` instance.

Since `pairs` is guaranteed to work for all Applicatives, and it does not work for your type, we can be sure your type is not Applicative. And since all Monads are also Applicative, we can conclude that your type cannot possibly be made an instance of Monad: it would violate the laws.